# Cannot set pointer location to that of another pointer's location in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a method that takes in a reference to a vector that contains pointers to objects as the first parameter, and a reference to a pointer to an object of the same type as the second parameter. Within the method, I want to change the location referenced by the second argument to an object within the vector. Then have the changed pointer be used by the caller of the method, having the new location as its target. However, my current attempts at implementing this are failing.

The method in question:

```
void execute(std::vector<CanvasElement*>& elements,CanvasElement*& lastFocused)
```

Examples of ways I've unsuccessfully tried setting the value pointed to by lastFocused:

```
lastFocused = elements[0];
*lastFocused = *elements[0];
```

An elaboration in reply to a comment below:
The failure is that the changes inside the function are not reflected once outside the scope of that function.

I can confirm by printing the addresses stored in each pointer during the application's runtime, that the value is indeed being set within execute, but outside of execute it wasn't changed.

Comment: The first one looks just right.

Comment: You are getting a compiler error or the pointer changed inside the function is not reflected outside ? i.e. can you elaborate what is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by storing a reference to the pointer in a vector and updating that stored reference. I do not know why setting it directly did not work, but this hack got the job done.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment `lastFocused = elements[0];` should work, here is a demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::string CanvasElement;

void execute(std::vector<CanvasElement*>& elements, CanvasElement*& lastFocused)
{
    lastFocused = elements[0];
}

int main()
{
    std::string a = "hello";
    std::string b = "world";

    std::vector<std::string*> vec;
    vec.push_back(&a);
    vec.push_back(&b);

    std::string* p = 0;
    execute(vec, p);
    if (p == &a)
    {
        std::cout << "It worked :-)\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "It did not work :-(\n";
    }
}
```

By the way, there are people who would argue that the following signature would be better:

```
CanvasElement* lastFocusedCanvasElement(std::vector<CanvasElement*>& elements)
```

That is, you should return a pointer value instead of changing a pointer variable.

Comment: Right, I agree with the last comment. I think returning the pointer, rather than having an argument passed by reference is a better option.

Comment: I agree that this is the better approach, but the current system with which I am working doesn't allow this behavior's implementation to be practically setup.